# Responsive table with PHP

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a table, which is supposed to be responsive. I have a little PHP script inside the table. When I try usual way of making it responsive, it isn't. I use a wrap Div svazTymy which is supposed to work like overflow container.

```
<div class="svazTymy">
    <TABLE>
        <TR>
            <th colspan="9">1. Národní hokejbalová liga 2014/2015</th>
        </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD width="39" height="19">Pořadí</TD>
        <TD width="394" height="19">Mužstvo</TD>
        <TD width="58" height="19">Z</TD>
        <TD width="58" height="19">V</TD>
        <TD width="59" height="19">VP</TD>
        <TD width="59" height="19">R</TD>
        <TD width="59" height="19">P</TD>
        <TD width="59" height="19">S</TD>
        <TD width="59" height="19">B</TD>
      </tr>        
            <?php
            // put your code here

        $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://hokejbal.cz/xml/2014-2015/tables/177.xml');
        foreach($xml->SKUPINA as $skupina){
            if($skupina['id_sku'] != 1164) continue;
            foreach($skupina->TYM as $tym){
                ?>
                  <tr <?php if($tym['kod_cmshb']==3202007){ ?> class="beroun" <?php } ?>>
                    <td><?=$tym["poradi"] ?>.</td>
                    <td><?=$tym["nazev"] ?></td>
                    <td><?=$tym->Z ?></td>
                    <td><?=$tym->V ?></td>
                    <td><?=$tym->VP ?></td>
                    <td><?=$tym->R ?></td>
                    <td><?=$tym->P ?></td>
                    <td><?=$tym->GH ?>:<?=$tym->GA ?></td>
                    <td><?=$tym->BODY ?></td>
                  </tr>        
                <?php
            }
            break;
        }

    ?>
    </TABLE>
        <p>Data převzata z <a href="http://hokejbal.cz"> hokejbal.cz</a></p> 
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/*Tabulky tymy*/

.svazTymy {
    overflow: auto;
    padding:10px;

}

.svazTymy  td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5
}


.svazTymy tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #006eb9;
    color:#fff;}
.svazTymy table tr:nth-child(1) td {
    font-weight : bolder;}   

.svazTymy tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}

.svazTymy table tr:nth-child(10) td {
    border-bottom : 3px solid red;}

.svazTymy tr.beroun {
    background-color: #825f5f;
}
```

I have tried also width:100%, didnt work as well. I am kind of lost. Can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: The widths you're setting on the first set of TDs is hard-setting the width of table. Removing those would probably help.

Comment: @castis thank you. The problem was in this and something else in the page. It is solved now.